# XCODE 5+ ... how to stop text in a TextView from jumping to just above keyboard when second line added?

Tags: ios, xcode, keyboard, uitextview

Relative newbie question: text entered in my textView is positioned at the top of the textview area until the text goes onto the second line at which point it jumps to the line just above the keyboard and then scrolls upwards as new lines are added. But I want the text to remain at the top of the textview until the text reaches the line above the keyboard and then scroll upwards. I can't figure out what to do to fix this.

I have spent some time searching and not found a simple example. Any suggestions are appreciated.

Comment: One thing I was unsure about is constraintToAdjust - at present it is set to Vert - Bottom Layout Guide - Text view

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the end, I downloaded the Apple Keyboard Accessory app and changed my code to match and it works now.
Here is the working code - but it is not meant to be an example of elegant code as I am an amateur:

```
#import "CREWGenericNotesVC.h"

@interface CREWGenericNotesVC ()

@property (nonatomic, weak) IBOutlet UIBarButtonItem *doneButton;
@property (nonatomic, weak) IBOutlet UITextView *textView;
// the height constraint we want to change when the keyboard shows/hides
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet NSLayoutConstraint *constraintToAdjust; 

// @property(nonatomic) CGSize contentSize;

@end

@implementation CREWGenericNotesVC

#define VIEW_NAME @"CREWGenericNotesVC" // need the name of the view that calls this
#define VIEW_DESCRIPTION @"Generic notes"
#define RETURN_NC @"NCEmergencyKitsList" // where to return to when complete processing 

- (void)viewDidLoad {

[super viewDidLoad];

//    [_textView addObserver:self forKeyPath:@"contentSize" options:  (NSKeyValueObservingOptionNew) context:NULL];

// load saved notes into textView

NSUserDefaults *defaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];


self.navigationItem.title = [defaults objectForKey:@"VCtitle"];
self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = self.doneButton;

[self initializeView];

}

// create and load entity and notes
- (void) initializeView
{
NSUserDefaults *defaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];

NSString *viewName = [defaults objectForKey:@"VCname"]; // parameter to specify which view is calling notes and
CREWAppDelegate *appDelegate = [[UIApplication sharedApplication]delegate];
NSManagedObjectContext *context = [appDelegate managedObjectContext];

NSEntityDescription *entityDesc = [NSEntityDescription entityForName:@"Notes" inManagedObjectContext:context];

NSFetchRequest * request = [[NSFetchRequest alloc] init];
[request setEntity:entityDesc];

NSPredicate *pred = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"(viewName = %@)", VIEW_NAME];
[request setPredicate:pred];

NSError *error = nil;
NSArray * objects = [context executeFetchRequest:request error:&error];

if ([objects count] == 0) { // create new notes instance if not already created
    [self newNotes:viewName]; //  create a new empty note object
} else {
    self.textView.text = [self getNotes:viewName];  //  load existing notes
}
} // end of initializeView

// create a new empty Notes record
- (void) newNotes:(NSString*)viewName
{
NSError *error = nil;
CREWAppDelegate *appDelegate = [[UIApplication sharedApplication]delegate];
NSManagedObjectContext *context = [appDelegate managedObjectContext];

NSManagedObject * newNotes;

newNotes = [NSEntityDescription insertNewObjectForEntityForName:@"Notes" inManagedObjectContext:context];

[newNotes setValue:viewName forKey:@"viewName"];
[newNotes setValue:nil forKey:@"viewNotes"];

if (! [context save:&error])
    NSLog(@"newNotes Couldn't save new data! Error:%@", [error description]); 
} // end of newNotes

// read existing notes
- (NSString*) getNotes:(NSString*)viewName// get stored notes
{
CREWAppDelegate *appDelegate = [[UIApplication sharedApplication]delegate];
NSManagedObjectContext *context = [appDelegate managedObjectContext];

NSEntityDescription *entityDesc = [NSEntityDescription entityForName:@"Notes" inManagedObjectContext:context];

NSFetchRequest * request = [[NSFetchRequest alloc] init];
[request setEntity:entityDesc];

NSPredicate *pred = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"(viewName = %@)", viewName];
[request setPredicate:pred];

// Execute Fetch Request
NSManagedObjectContext * matches = nil;
NSError *fetchError = nil;
NSArray *objects = [appDelegate.managedObjectContext executeFetchRequest:request error:&fetchError];
if (fetchError) {
    NSLog(@"getNotes Fetch error:%@", fetchError); 
};

NSString *viewNotes;

if (! [objects count] == 0) {
    matches = objects [0];
    viewNotes = [matches valueForKey : @"viewNotes"];
}
return viewNotes;
} // end of getNotes

- (void)saveNotes:(NSString*)viewName toValue:(NSString*)newNotes // to get stored notes and update them
{
CREWAppDelegate *appDelegate = [[UIApplication sharedApplication]delegate];
NSManagedObjectContext *context = [appDelegate managedObjectContext];

NSEntityDescription *entityDesc = [NSEntityDescription entityForName:@"Notes" inManagedObjectContext:context]; // get notes entity

NSFetchRequest * request = [[NSFetchRequest alloc] init];
[request setEntity:entityDesc];

NSPredicate *pred = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"(viewName = %@)", viewName ];
[request setPredicate:pred];

NSManagedObject *matches = nil;
NSError *error = nil;
NSArray * objects = [context executeFetchRequest:request error:&error];

if (![objects count] == 0) {
    matches = objects[0];
}
[matches setValue:newNotes forKey:@"viewNotes"];

if (! [context save:&error]) NSLog(@"newNotes Couldn't save notes! Error:%@", [error description]);
} // end of saveSwitch

// keyboard stuff

- (void)viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated {

// observe keyboard hide and show notifications to resize the text view appropriately
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self
                                         selector:@selector(keyboardWillShow:)
                                             name:UIKeyboardWillShowNotification
                                           object:nil];
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self
                                         selector:@selector(keyboardWillHide:)
                                             name:UIKeyboardWillHideNotification
                                           object:nil];

// start editing the UITextView (makes the keyboard appear when the application launches)
[self editAction:self];
}

- (void)viewDidDisappear:(BOOL)animated {

[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] removeObserver:self
                                                name:UIKeyboardWillChangeFrameNotification
                                              object:nil];
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] removeObserver:self
                                                name:UIKeyboardWillHideNotification
                                              object:nil];
}

- (void)didRotateFromInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)fromInterfaceOrientation {
[self adjustSelection:self.textView];
}

#pragma mark - Actions

- (IBAction)doneAction:(id)sender  {

// user tapped the Done button, release first responder on the text view
[self.textView resignFirstResponder];

NSUserDefaults *defaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];

NSString *viewName = [defaults objectForKey:@"VCname"]; // parameter to specify where to save notes
//    NSString *stringNC = [defaults objectForKey:@"NCname"]; // parameter to specify which navigation controller to return to
[self saveNotes:viewName toValue: self.textView.text]; // save notes

[defaults stringForKey:@"NCname"];
UIViewController *viewController = [[UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"Main" bundle:nil] instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:[defaults stringForKey:@"NCname"]]; 
[self presentViewController:viewController animated:YES completion:nil];
}

- (IBAction)editAction:(id)sender {

// user tapped the Edit button, make the text view first responder
[self.textView becomeFirstResponder];
}

#pragma mark - UITextViewDelegate

- (BOOL)textViewShouldBeginEditing:(UITextView *)aTextView {
}

self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = self.doneButton;

return YES;
}

- (BOOL)textViewShouldEndEditing:(UITextView *)aTextView {

[aTextView resignFirstResponder];

return YES;
}

- (void)adjustSelection:(UITextView *)textView {

// workaround to UITextView bug, text at the very bottom is slightly cropped by the keyboard
if ([textView respondsToSelector:@selector(textContainerInset)]) {
    [textView layoutIfNeeded];
    CGRect caretRect = [textView caretRectForPosition:textView.selectedTextRange.end];
    caretRect.size.height += textView.textContainerInset.bottom;
    [textView scrollRectToVisible:caretRect animated:NO];
}
}

- (void)textViewDidBeginEditing:(UITextView *)textView {

[self adjustSelection:textView];
}

- (void)textViewDidChangeSelection:(UITextView *)textView {

[self adjustSelection:textView];
}


#pragma mark - Responding to keyboard events

- (void)adjustTextViewByKeyboardState:(BOOL)showKeyboard keyboardInfo:(NSDictionary *)info {

/*
 Reduce the size of the text view so that it's not obscured by the keyboard.
 Animate the resize so that it's in sync with the appearance of the keyboard.
 */

// transform the UIViewAnimationCurve to a UIViewAnimationOptions mask
UIViewAnimationCurve animationCurve = [info[UIKeyboardAnimationCurveUserInfoKey] unsignedIntegerValue];
UIViewAnimationOptions animationOptions = UIViewAnimationOptionBeginFromCurrentState;
if (animationCurve == UIViewAnimationCurveEaseIn) {
    animationOptions |= UIViewAnimationOptionCurveEaseIn;
}
else if (animationCurve == UIViewAnimationCurveEaseInOut) {
    animationOptions |= UIViewAnimationOptionCurveEaseInOut;
}
else if (animationCurve == UIViewAnimationCurveEaseOut) {
    animationOptions |= UIViewAnimationOptionCurveEaseOut;
}
else if (animationCurve == UIViewAnimationCurveLinear) {
    animationOptions |= UIViewAnimationOptionCurveLinear;
}

[self.textView setNeedsUpdateConstraints];

if (showKeyboard) {
    UIDeviceOrientation orientation = self.interfaceOrientation;
    BOOL isPortrait = UIDeviceOrientationIsPortrait(orientation);

    NSValue *keyboardFrameVal = [info objectForKey:UIKeyboardFrameEndUserInfoKey];
    CGRect keyboardFrame = [keyboardFrameVal CGRectValue];
    CGFloat height = isPortrait ? keyboardFrame.size.height : keyboardFrame.size.width;

    // adjust the constraint constant to include the keyboard's height
    self.constraintToAdjust.constant += height;
}
else {
    self.constraintToAdjust.constant = 0;
}

NSTimeInterval animationDuration = [[info objectForKey:UIKeyboardAnimationDurationUserInfoKey] doubleValue];

[UIView animateWithDuration:animationDuration delay:0 options:animationOptions animations:^{
    [self.view layoutIfNeeded];
} completion:nil];

// now that the frame has changed, move to the selection or point of edit
NSRange selectedRange = self.textView.selectedRange;
[self.textView scrollRangeToVisible:selectedRange];
}

- (void)keyboardWillShow:(NSNotification *)notification {

/*
 Reduce the size of the text view so that it's not obscured by the keyboard.
 Animate the resize so that it's in sync with the appearance of the keyboard.
 */

NSDictionary *userInfo = [notification userInfo];
[self adjustTextViewByKeyboardState:YES keyboardInfo:userInfo];
}

- (void)keyboardWillHide:(NSNotification *)notification {

/*
 Restore the size of the text view (fill self's view).
 Animate the resize so that it's in sync with the disappearance of the keyboard.
 */

NSDictionary *userInfo = [notification userInfo];
[self adjustTextViewByKeyboardState:NO keyboardInfo:userInfo];
}

@end
```

Comment: Can you strip everything not directly related to the problem out of this?

Comment: This question was posted nearly a year ago. Since then I have converted the application to use Swift.